# extract file content to mutliple files base on match pattern

Tags: linux, unix, shell, script

I am new to unix. I would like to process this file.

```
PP_NAME_1
jprovider|J Driver Provider|${J_DRIVER_PATH}/jcc;${J_DRIVER_PATH}/jcc_license_cu|${J_DRIVER_NATIVEPATH}|com.jcc.Connection
source|BDBDDS|dbc/chuchchu|JDriver Provider|node/chuchchu_ias|chuchchu|password|CHCHCH|4|serverName|portNumber
save
PP_NAME_2
classPath|/mm/ja/lib
customProperty|AppContent.Directory|-8
customProperty|javx.toreType|-8
customProperty|javax.tore|-8
save
PP_NAME_3
classPath|/mm/ja/lib
customProperty|AppContent.Directory|-8
customProperty|javx.toreType|-8
customProperty|javax.tore|-8
Alias|461bdhk_host|123.45.67.89|10000
source|BDBDDS|dbc/chuchchu|JDriver Provider|node/chuchchu_s|chuchchu|password|CHCHCH|4|serverName|portNumber
Variable|J_DRIVER_PATH|
save
PP_NAME_4
classPath|/mm/ja/lib
Variable|J_DRIVER_PATH|
save
```

I would like to extract lines next to match pattern PP_NAME_1 to first save pattern into FILE1

Then lines next to match pattern PP_NAME_2 to second save pattern into FILE2 and so on.

There will be not empty lines in original file.

U will observer the lines vary for each file.

FILE1 will have 3 lines

FILE2 will have 5 lines

FILE3 will have 8 lines

and

FILE4 will have 3 lines.

So, lines will vary everytime, there could be more than 50 lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `awk` with `PP_NAME_` as the record separator:

```
awk -v RS='PP_NAME_' -v FS='\n' '/./ {print | "tail -n +2 >FILE"$1}' input
```

`awk` reads in a "record" at a time and divides each record into "fields".  In this case, the use `RS='PP_NAME_'` defines a record as all the text up to the next instance of the characters `PP_NAME_`.  The field separator, `FS`, is equal to a new line.  That means that each line is a "field".  Defined this way, each record begins with a line containing the number of the file to which we want to write the record.  The actual writing of the record to the file is done with: `print | "tail -n +2 >FILE"$1`.  Since `$1` is the number that remains on the first line, `"FILE"$1` is the name of the output file that we want to write.  We want to write everything in the record to that file *except* for the first line which has the number.  The use of the shell command `tail -n +2` removes that first line.

The first record read in is all the text before the first occurrence of `PP_NAME_`.  That means that the first record read in is empty.  Since we don't want to write that out, the regular expression `/./` is placed before the `print` command.  This regex matches any non-empty record.  That means it eliminates the empty record that we didn't want.

Comment: Could you expand on what this command does?

Comment: @DoktoroReichard `awk` can be impressively terse.  Some explanation added.